# How to solve for x in this eq

Tags: arithmetic

I'm doing a physics E&M problem, but I'm stuck on a math part. I can't remember how to solve for x in this instance.

${x\over 2}  = {0.04-x\over 5}$

Comment: Here's a hint: If $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d}$, then $a\cdot d = b\cdot c$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

1. Multiply each side of the equation by $10$.
2. Add $2x$ to each side of the equation.
3. Divide each side of the equation by $7$.

Answer (score 0):

Solve it like any other algebra problem like this. Isolate $x$ to one side and then make the necessary multiplications.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{x}{2}=\frac{0.04-x}{5} \Rightarrow \frac{x}{2}+\frac{x}{5}=\frac{0.04}{5} \\ \Rightarrow \frac{7x}{10}=\frac{0.04}{5} \Rightarrow x=\frac{10}{7}\times \frac{0.04}{5}$

Comment: $\frac{x}{2}=\frac{0.04-x}{5} \Rightarrow \frac{x}{2}+\frac{x}{5}=0.04/5 $